# Simple method to calculate power of a number without any extern function

Tags: function, loops

I look for a simple method for calculating the power of a number without using any extern function, only one loop and one if/else condition.
It takes only an integer for power (positive, negative and zero).
I make this function in pseudo language if anybody knows another method?

```
function power(x,n)
{
    var index, result=1;
     
        if (n<0) then
        {
            x=1/x; 
            n=-n;
        }
        
        foreach index from 0 to n
        {
            result=result*x;
        }
       
      return result;        
}
```